# Elegant way to create two different random integers

Tags: matlab, random

I want to create two random integers on the interval `[1,n]` which are guaranteed to be different from each other. I feel like

```
ri(1)=randi([1 n]);
ri(2)=randi([1 n]);
while ri(1)==ri(2)
  ri(2)=randi([1 n]);
end
```

is not really the smoothest thing you can do.

Comment: p = [randperm(n, k)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) returns a row vector containing k **unique** integers selected randomly from 1 to n inclusive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One method is to use [`randperm`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) so that you generate a random permutation of `n` values that are enumerated from `1` up to and including `n`, and only return the first two elements of the result:

```
ri = randperm(n, 2);
```

Older versions of MATLAB do not support calling `randperm` this way.  Older versions only accept the one input variant, which by default returns the entire permutation of the `n` values.  Therefore, you can call `randperm` using the one input version, then subset into the final result to return what you need:

```
ri = randperm(n);
ri = ri([1 2]);
```

Comment: Exactly. From the documentation on `randi`: "The arrays returned by randi might contain repeated integer values. This is sometimes referred to as sampling with replacement. To get unique integer values, sometimes referred to as sampling without replacement, use randperm (RandStream)."

Comment: @EdwardCarney Yes I was aware :) Thank you.

Comment: @rayryeng thanks for the solution. And sorry for not checking `randi` documentation. I was on the `rand`-documentation where they tell you about `randi` and somehow didn't think about checking the `randi` documentation....

Comment: @Max Don't worry about it at all.  I didn't even look at the documentation... I just knew from experience :)

Comment: @Max if you wish to include `0's` then go for `vec = randperm(n+1, 2)` `vec = vec-1`;

Comment: @TonyTannous True, but the original question only asked between `1` and `n`.  Good workaround though.

Comment: Good idea! It wouln'd have occurred to me to use `randperm`

Answer (score 2):

Use `randperm` to create two unique values in range 1...n

```
out = randperm(n, 2)
out(1) = number 1
out(2) = number 2
```

If you wish to include 0's in your range. then:

```
out = randperm(n+1, 2);
out = out-1;
out(1) = number 1
out(2) = number 2
```

Comment: @rayryeng, true... I come from `C` world where start index is `0` :)

Comment: @tonytannous thanks for your answer and for the additional information as well. I'll accept ray's solution since he postet first, but you got my upvote ;)

Comment: @Max :) happy to help. Yes his answer explained also how `randperm` works behind the scenes. I just skipped that part :D

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way:

```
ri(1) = randi([1 n]); % choose ri(1) uniformly from the set 1,...,n
ri(2) = randi([1 n-1]); % choose ri(2) uniformly from 1,...,n-1
ri(2) = ri(2) + (ri(2)>=ri(1)); % transform 1,...,n-1 into 1,...,ri(1)-1,ri(1)+1,...,n
```

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks for your approach as well. It wouldn't really matter for me, but from a mathematical point of view these numbers wouldn't be stochastically indepent, or would they?

Comment: @Max The numbers are not independent. They cannot be, with this or with any other approach. Since you want the two numbers to be different, knowing one does tell you something about the other, so they are not independent. What you want (judging from your code) is to produce all pairs if different numbers with the same probability. And that's what my code does. Consider `n=7`. If `ri(1)` is for example `3`, the second and third lines pick `ri(2)` uniformly from the set `1`, `2`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`. I have added some comments in the code to clarify

Comment: @LuisMendo yes, you are right, what i meant was if `ri(2)` was uniformly distributed on that set. Thanks for the explanation